# CNN in python. Array of images

Tags: python, arrays, conv-neural-network

I was trying to deeply search for a solution online before posting here, but I couldn't find it.  My problem arises during the reading of images in a training of a convolutional neural network.  Basically, I decided to create a function creating the in values and the out values out of a series of images.  I want to read all the images of the set, but not all at the same time, to avoid running out of memory, so I create the next function:

```
def readImages(strSet = 'Train', nIni = 1, nFin = 20):

if strSet not in ('Train','Test'):
    return None
# 
# Inicializamos los arrays de salida: las imágenes y las etiquetas.
arrImages = []
arrLabels = []
#
# Recorremos todos y cada uno de los directorios dentro del set elegido
for strDir in os.listdir(data_dir+'/' + strSet + '/'):
    # Nombre de la clase que estamos tratando.
    strClass = strDir[strDir.find('-')+1:]
    # Número y nombre de los ficheros, por si es menor que el número n indicado.
    arrNameFiles = os.listdir(data_dir+'/' + strSet + '/'+strDir)
    nFiles = len(os.listdir(data_dir+'/' + strSet + '/'+strDir))
    #
    # Cogemos los ficheros desde el nIni al nFin. De esta forma nos aseguramos los cogemos todos en cada directorio.
    #print('nImagesClase(',strSet,',',strClass,'):',nImagesClase(strSet, strClass))
    if (nIni == -1):
        # Si el valor es -1, cogemos todas las imágenes del directorio.            
        listChosenFiles = arrNameFiles
        #print('Todos: ', len(listChosenFiles))
    else:
        if (nImagesClase(strSet, strClass)<nFin):
            # Si ya hemos dado la vuelta a todos los ficheros del grupo, los cogemos al azar.
            listChosenFiles = random.sample(arrNameFiles, min(nFiles, nFin-nIni))
            #print('Fin del directorio ',nFin,'>',nImagesClase(strSet,strClass),': ', len(listChosenFiles))
        else:
            # Si no, seguimos.
            listChosenFiles = arrNameFiles[nIni-1:min(nFin,nImagesClase(strSet, strClass))-1]
            #print('Seguimos ',nIni,'-',nFin,': ', len(listChosenFiles))
    #
    for file in listChosenFiles:
        # Lectura del fichero.
        image = plt.imread(data_dir+'/'+strSet+'/'+strDir+'/'+file)
        #print('Original Shape: ',image.shape)
        #plt.imshow(image)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (crop_width, crop_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
        #image = image.reshape((image_height,image_width,num_channels))
        #print('Al array de imágenes: ',image.shape)
        arrImages.append(image)
        # Añadimos etiquetas.
        arrLabel = np.zeros(n_classes)
        arrLabel[array_classes.index(strClass)] = 1
        arrLabels.append(arrLabel)
#
# Recogemos los valores de entrada y salida en arrays.
y = np.array(arrLabels)
X = np.array(arrImages, dtype=np.uint8)
# Una vez terminado el recorrido por todas las imágenes, reordenamos los índices para que no vayan las imágenes en secuendias de la misma clase.
arrIndexes = np.arange(X.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(arrIndexes)
X = X[arrIndexes]
y = y[arrIndexes]
#
return X, y
```

To test the behavior of this function I just execute the following line.

```
X, y = readImages(strSet = 'Train', nIni = 1, nFin = 5)
```

Which is ok, until the moment **nIni** and **nFin** reach some values (101-105, for example).  In that moment, I receive the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-8a690256a1fc> in <module>
----> 1 X, y = readImages(strSet = 'Train', nIni = 101, nFin = 105)

<ipython-input-123-9e9ebc660c33> in readImages(strSet, nIni, nFin)
     50     # Recogemos los valores de entrada y salida en arrays.
     51     y = np.array(arrLabels)
---> 52     X = np.array(arrImages, dtype=np.uint8)
     53     # Una vez terminado el recorrido por todas las imágenes, reordenamos los índices para que no vayan las imágenes en secuendias de la misma clase.
     54     arrIndexes = np.arange(X.shape[0])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (28,28,3) into shape (28,28)
```

I put some print traces in the reading of the images, and everyone of the read images has a shape of (28,28,3), so I don't really understand from where do I have this (28,28) shape pointed out in the error trace.

Do you know what could be the problem?  Did you face this problem earlier?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your images have single channels. Use `cv2.imread` instead of `plt.imread`

`image = cv2.imread(data_dir+'/'+strSet+'/'+strDir+'/'+file)`

Comment: Thanks. Now it works well. But I don't understand the difference.  I put in any iteration the shape of all of the images, and all of them had the num_channels dimension.